# Configure OpenSSH server and router to accept SSH connection over internet?

Tags: ssh

I want to access my PC from anywhere. I'm able to connect to the PC within the same LAN using the local IP. However, outside the local network I see a connection time out error.

How can I configure my OpenSSH server on Host and my router to allow SSH connections from anywhere over the internet?

Comment: Are you using the laptop inside the same network? If not, your modem/router's firewall could be blocking it.

Comment: Is your PC directly connected to the Internet? If not, did you enable port forwarding on your router? Can you connect within the same LAN,  using the local IP?

Comment: right now I'm inside the same network. but that's why I used noip to access it from anywhere.

Comment: I didn't try port forwarding . I'm able to connect to the PC within the LAN using local IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your remote Client, your home router, and your Host server to cooperate in creating an SSH connection on the same Port. Use port-forwarding within your router's configuration to forward the correct port (e.g., Port 22) to the local IP address of your Host server.

- Port-forwarding settings should be present inside "NAT" or "Virtual Network" on the 192.168.1.1 page you use to configure your router :)
- `ifconfig` on Host server will show its current local IP. Use `nm-connection-editor` to generate a Static IP address for this machine if it's not Static already.
- Host server listens for SSH connection on Port listed in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: maybe you need to access you router setup some other way, but the part about configuring the forward is most likely spot on.